# Can put xml reader function into D3drenderer.cs?

Tags: c#, xml, directshow, direct3d, directshow.net

Below is the standard d3drenderer.cs file coding:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The D3DRenderer class provides basic functionality needed
    /// to render a D3D surface.  This class is abstract.
    /// </summary>
public abstract class D3DRenderer : FrameworkElement
{
    private string workingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    /// <summary>
    /// The D3DImage used to render video
    /// </summary>
    private D3DImage m_d3dImage;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Image control that has the source
    /// to the D3DImage
    /// </summary>
    private Image m_videoImage;

    /// <summary>
    /// We keep reference to the D3D surface so
    /// we can delay loading it to avoid a black flicker
    /// when loading new media
    /// </summary>
    private IntPtr m_pBackBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;

    /// <summary>
    /// Flag to tell us if we have a new D3D
    /// Surface available
    /// </summary>
    private bool m_newSurfaceAvailable;

    /// <summary>
    /// A weak reference of D3DRenderers that have been cloned
    /// </summary>
    private readonly List<WeakReference> m_clonedD3Drenderers = new List<WeakReference>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Backing field for the RenderOnCompositionTargetRendering flag. 
    /// </summary>
    private bool m_renderOnCompositionTargetRendering;

    /// <summary>
    /// Temporary storage for the RenderOnCompositionTargetRendering flag.
    /// This is used to remember the value for when the control is loaded and unloaded.
    /// </summary>
    private bool m_renderOnCompositionTargetRenderingTemp;

    #region Stretch
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StretchProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Stretch", typeof(Stretch), typeof(D3DRenderer),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Stretch.Uniform,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnStretchChanged)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines what rules are applied to the stretching of the video
    /// </summary>
    public Stretch Stretch
    {
        get { return (Stretch)GetValue(StretchProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StretchProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnStretchChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((D3DRenderer)d).OnStretchChanged(e);
    }

    private void OnStretchChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_videoImage.Stretch = (Stretch) e.NewValue;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IsRenderingEnabled

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRenderingEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsRenderingEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(D3DRenderer),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));

    /// <summary>
    /// Enables or disables rendering of the video
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsRenderingEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsRenderingEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsRenderingEnabledProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region NaturalVideoHeight

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey NaturalVideoHeightPropertyKey
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("NaturalVideoHeight", typeof(int), typeof(MediaElementBase),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NaturalVideoHeightProperty
        = NaturalVideoHeightPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the natural pixel height of the current media.  
    /// The value will be 0 if there is no video in the media.
    /// </summary>
    public int NaturalVideoHeight
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NaturalVideoHeightProperty); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal method to set the read-only NaturalVideoHeight DP
    /// </summary>
    protected void SetNaturalVideoHeight(int value)
    {
        SetValue(NaturalVideoHeightPropertyKey, value);
    }

    #endregion

    #region NaturalVideoWidth

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey NaturalVideoWidthPropertyKey
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("NaturalVideoWidth", typeof(int), typeof(MediaElementBase),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NaturalVideoWidthProperty
        = NaturalVideoWidthPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the natural pixel width of the current media.
    /// The value will be 0 if there is no video in the media.
    /// </summary>
    public int NaturalVideoWidth
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NaturalVideoWidthProperty); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal method to set the read-only NaturalVideoWidth DP
    /// </summary>
    protected void SetNaturalVideoWidth(int value)
    {
        SetValue(NaturalVideoWidthPropertyKey, value);
    }

    #endregion

    #region HasVideo

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasVideoPropertyKey
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("HasVideo", typeof(bool), typeof(MediaElementBase),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasVideoProperty
        = HasVideoPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Is true if the media contains renderable video
    /// </summary>
    public bool HasVideo
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasVideoProperty); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal method for setting the read-only HasVideo DP
    /// </summary>
    protected void SetHasVideo(bool value)
    {
        SetValue(HasVideoPropertyKey, value);
    }
    #endregion

    protected D3DRenderer()
    {
        InitializeD3DVideo();

        /* Hook into the framework events */
        Loaded += D3DRenderer_Loaded;
        Unloaded += D3DRenderer_Unloaded;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for when the D3DRenderer is unloaded
    /// </summary>
    private void D3DRenderer_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* Remember what the property value was */
        m_renderOnCompositionTargetRenderingTemp = RenderOnCompositionTargetRendering;

        /* Make sure to unhook the static event hook because we are unloading */
        RenderOnCompositionTargetRendering = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for when the D3DRenderer is loaded
    /// </summary>
    private void D3DRenderer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* Restore the property's value */
        RenderOnCompositionTargetRendering = m_renderOnCompositionTargetRenderingTemp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the D3DRenderer control
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void InitializeD3DVideo()
    {
        if (m_videoImage != null)
            return;

        /* Create our Image and it's D3DImage source */
        m_videoImage = new Image();
        m_d3dImage = new D3DImage();

        /* We hook into this event to handle when a D3D device is lost */
        D3DImage.IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged += D3DImage_IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged;

        /* Set our default stretch value of our video */
        m_videoImage.Stretch = (Stretch)StretchProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue;
        var activeProfiles = XElement.Load(workingDirectory + "ProfilesDisplay.xml");
        var a = activeProfiles.Element("_nABC").Value;

        /* Our source of the video image is the D3DImage */
        m_videoImage.Source = D3DImage;

        /* Register the Image as a visual child */
        AddVisualChild(m_videoImage);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This should only fire when a D3D device is lost
    /// </summary>
    private void D3DImage_IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!D3DImage.IsFrontBufferAvailable)
            return;

        /* Flag that we have a new surface, even
         * though we really don't */
        m_newSurfaceAvailable = true;

        /* Force feed the D3DImage the Surface pointer */
        SetBackBufferInternal(m_pBackBuffer);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        m_videoImage.Measure(availableSize);
        return m_videoImage.DesiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        m_videoImage.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index > 0)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

        return m_videoImage;
    }

    protected D3DImage D3DImage
    {
        get
        {
            return m_d3dImage;
        }
    }

    protected Image VideoImage
    {
        get
        {
            return m_videoImage;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Renders the video with WPF's rendering using the CompositionTarget.Rendering event
    /// </summary>
    protected bool RenderOnCompositionTargetRendering
    {
        get
        {
            return m_renderOnCompositionTargetRendering;
        }
        set
        {
            /* If it is being set to true and it was previously false
             * then hook into the event */
            if (value && !m_renderOnCompositionTargetRendering)
                CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
            else if(!value)
                CompositionTarget.Rendering -= CompositionTarget_Rendering;

            m_renderOnCompositionTargetRendering = value;
            m_renderOnCompositionTargetRenderingTemp = value;
        }
    }

    private void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InternalInvalidateVideoImage();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used as a clone for a D3DRenderer
    /// </summary>
    private class ClonedD3DRenderer : D3DRenderer
    {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a clone of the D3DRenderer.  This is a work for the visual
    /// brush not working cross-threaded
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public D3DRenderer CloneD3DRenderer()
    {
        var renderer = new ClonedD3DRenderer();

        lock(m_clonedD3Drenderers)
        {
            m_clonedD3Drenderers.Add(new WeakReference(renderer));
        }

        renderer.SetBackBuffer(m_pBackBuffer);
        return renderer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cleans up any dead references we may have to any cloned renderers
    /// </summary>
    private void CleanZombieRenderers()
    {
        lock(m_clonedD3Drenderers)
        {
            var deadObjects = new List<WeakReference>();

            for (int i = 0; i < m_clonedD3Drenderers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!m_clonedD3Drenderers[i].IsAlive)
                    deadObjects.Add(m_clonedD3Drenderers[i]);
            }

            foreach(var deadGuy in deadObjects)
            {
                m_clonedD3Drenderers.Remove(deadGuy);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures D3DImage with a new surface.  The back buffer is
    /// not set until we actually receive a frame, this way we
    /// can avoid a black flicker between media changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="backBuffer">The unmanaged pointer to the Direct3D Surface</param>
    protected void SetBackBuffer(IntPtr backBuffer)
    {
        /* We only do this if target rendering is enabled because we must use an Invoke
         * instead of a BeginInvoke to keep the Surfaces in sync and Invoke could be dangerous
         * in other situations */
        if(RenderOnCompositionTargetRendering)
        {
            if (!D3DImage.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                D3DImage.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => SetBackBuffer(backBuffer)), DispatcherPriority.Render);
                return;
            }
        }

        /* Flag a new surface */
        m_newSurfaceAvailable = true;
        m_pBackBuffer = backBuffer;

        /* Make a special case for target rendering */
        if (RenderOnCompositionTargetRendering)
        {
            SetBackBufferInternal(m_pBackBuffer);
        }

        SetBackBufferForClones();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the backbuffer for any cloned D3DRenderers
    /// </summary>
    private void SetBackBufferForClones()
    {
        lock (m_clonedD3Drenderers)
        {
            CleanZombieRenderers();

            foreach (var rendererRef in m_clonedD3Drenderers)
            {
                var renderer = rendererRef.Target as D3DRenderer;
                if (renderer != null)
                    renderer.SetBackBuffer(m_pBackBuffer);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures D3DImage with a new surface.  This happens immediately
    /// </summary>
    private void SetBackBufferInternal(IntPtr backBuffer)
    {
        /* Do nothing if we don't have a new surface available */
        if (!m_newSurfaceAvailable)
            return;

        if(!D3DImage.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            D3DImage.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => SetBackBufferInternal(backBuffer)));
            return;
        }

        /* We have this around a try/catch just in case we
         * lose the device and our Surface is invalid. The
         * try/catch may not be needed, but testing needs
         * to take place before it's removed */
        try
        {
            D3DImage.Lock();
            D3DImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, backBuffer);
            D3DImage.Unlock();
            SetNaturalWidthHeight();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

        /* Clear our flag, so this won't be ran again
         * until a new surface is sent */
        m_newSurfaceAvailable = false;
    }

    private void SetNaturalWidthHeight()
    {
        SetNaturalVideoHeight(m_d3dImage.PixelHeight);
        SetNaturalVideoWidth(m_d3dImage.PixelWidth);
    }

    protected void InvalidateVideoImage()
    {
        if (!m_renderOnCompositionTargetRendering)
            InternalInvalidateVideoImage();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invalidates the entire Direct3D image, notifying WPF to redraw
    /// </summary>
    protected void InternalInvalidateVideoImage()
    {
        /* Ensure we run on the correct Dispatcher */
        if(!D3DImage.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            D3DImage.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => InvalidateVideoImage()));
            return;
        }

        /* If there is a new Surface to set,
         * this method will do the trick */
        SetBackBufferInternal(m_pBackBuffer);

        /* Only render the video image if possible, or if IsRenderingEnabled is true */
        if (D3DImage.IsFrontBufferAvailable && IsRenderingEnabled && m_pBackBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Invalidate the entire image */
                D3DImage.Lock();
                D3DImage.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, /* Left */
                                                    0, /* Top */
                                                    D3DImage.PixelWidth, /* Width */
                                                    D3DImage.PixelHeight /* Height */));
                D3DImage.Unlock();
            }
            catch
            { }
        }

        /* Invalidate all of our cloned D3DRenderers */
        InvalidateClonedVideoImages();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invalidates any possible cloned renderer we may have
    /// </summary>
    private void InvalidateClonedVideoImages()
    {
        lock(m_clonedD3Drenderers)
        {
            CleanZombieRenderers();

            foreach(var rendererRef in m_clonedD3Drenderers)
            {
                var renderer = rendererRef.Target as D3DRenderer;
                if(renderer != null)
                    renderer.InvalidateVideoImage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

In the *InitializeD3DVideo()* function, I try to read a xml file from a location from the harddisk. But it can't be done.

Is it that the d3drenderer.cs cannot read from a xml file? I just want to read a value from _nABC of the xml file.

Comment: The xml may contain errors.  To check for errors post the xml into following view Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Errors will show in Error List just like any compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the D3DRenderer.

The path to the XML file is wrong. There is a '/' (or '\') missing between the `workingDirectory` and the `+ "ProfilesDisplay.xml"`.
If you don't know your path strings, the best method to combine these is [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx).